# Mouse event name

Tags: jquery

You might find this quite simple...I just don't know the name of the event I am looking for.

Right now, I store the width and height of an image.
I store the width and height of an image where I click.

I would like to to the same thing when the "click button stop being pressed in the specific div" in order to have the x,y start position of the click, and the x,y end position of the click in order to be able to have all of the built rectangle position.

This is what I have for now

```
$(document).on("click", "#img_to_deal_with", function(e){
    let maxH = $('#img_to_deal_with').height();
    let maxL = $('#img_to_deal_with').width();  
    let posX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    let posY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    console.log("Height : " + maxH);
    console.log("Width : " + maxL);
    console.log("Current Height : "+ posY);
    console.log("Current Width :" + posX);
});
```

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Simply google list of events: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-list-events-bind/ I think you are looking for `mouseup`

Comment: mouse release event. i.e `mouse up` https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseup.asp

Comment: Thanks...I was lost in the whole list....sorry. Indeed it's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mousedown:** Fires when the user depresses the mouse button.
**mouseup:** Fires when the user releases the mouse button.
**click:** Fires when a mousedown and mouseup event occur on the same element.
[source](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)

So you probably want to separate the *click* in *mousedown* and *mouseup*:

```js
$(document).on("mousedown", "#img_to_deal_with", function(e){
    let maxH = $('#img_to_deal_with').height();
    let maxL = $('#img_to_deal_with').width();  
    let posX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    let posY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    console.log("Height : " + maxH);
    console.log("Width : " + maxL);
    console.log("Down Height : "+ posY);
    console.log("Down Width :" + posX);
}).on("mouseup", "#img_to_deal_with", function(e){
    let maxH = $('#img_to_deal_with').height();
    let maxL = $('#img_to_deal_with').width();  
    let posX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    let posY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    console.log("Height : " + maxH);
    console.log("Width : " + maxL);
    console.log("Up Height : "+ posY);
    console.log("Up Width :" + posX);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-150-9.jpg" id="img_to_deal_with" draggable="false">
```

Comment: Yes this is what I figure out. Plus, as the object is an image...it need to be draggable false or the mouseup can't be fired.

Comment: @Minirock yeah, you are right. I wasn't sure if the ID was from the actual image. I updated my answer.